# Rake - running a sequence of tasks

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm using Rake to compile some annoying LaTeX stuff.

As a matter of fact, I'd like to **clean** my working dir *before* and *after* compiling.
So I defined two tasks: `:clean` and `:compile`.

Somehow naively, I wrote this:

```
task :default => [:clean, :compile, :clean]
```

but, as I discovered a little later while reading Rake's docs, this won't work because the array of tasks contains *dependencies*, not actions to make.

So, is there a clean way to execute a sequence of tasks without invoking them manually with `Rake::Task("clean")` etc.?
Something similar to the dependencies array.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your dependencies and rely on rake to figure out a valid order. Of course you will have a little trouble to execute the :clean task more than once, but you can [reenable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391834/how-to-call-rake-target-twice) it or use an [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656541/the-alias-of-task-name-in-rake). Or you can define

```
def clean
   ...
end

task :default => [:clean_after_compile]
task :clean_after_compile => [:compile] do clean end
task :compile => [:clean_before_compile]
task :clean_before_compile => [:compile] do clean end
```

in order to stay somewhat dry. As rake deals with dependencies and not with sequences it might just turn out to be a little more work than you liked.